# I am trying to show a div conditionally, only if the page is framed on a domain besides my own

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, window.location

example domain : mydomain.com

```
if(location.hostname.indexOf("mydomain") >= 0){
  $("#load").css({display: "none"});
}
```

this is currently working to hide the div, but even on a different domain it is hiding the div, which i think may be caused by the iframe is still mydomain? I asked this before and it got deleted, but i got a response which was sort of like the above code. i changed it to get the hostname, since `window.parent.location` would show the div still for some people on my website. i also tried with an else statement to display block, which didn't render any different result. thanks for your time.

Comment: if you can access parent.location, then your iframe is same domain as container ... if not, then it's a different domain (parent.location may still be accessible, other things are not though - but it gives you a start)

Comment: @JaromandaX so you're suggesting i check for `parent.location` ? I wonder if `top.location` would reference the domain the frame is on as well? before trying `window.parent.location` the div worked how i wanted it to for me only it seemed, and then would show even on my domain for everyone else. which i found weird. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the top url using the document location and referrer; so your final code would look something like this:

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer : document.location.href;
if(url.indexOf("mydomain") >= 0){
   $("#load").css({display: "none"});
}
```

**Edit:**

To get the hostname from document.referrer, it may be necessary to do some parsing:

```
function getHost(fullURL){ 
   return fullURL.split('/')[2]
}

//Usage:
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? getHost(document.referrer) : document.location.href;
```

Comment: thank you, I attempted this and it does indeed display none on my domain, but also on other domains. Could this be because the domain i am checking on, includes `mydomain` in the path?

Comment: Ah, did not realize that could be a factor. You could use this to parse the host from the full path: function getHost(fullURL){ return fullURL.split('/')[2]}

Answer (score 0):

Well location.hostName will be your page in the iframe, you are not looking at the parent page's host name. So you would need to look at the parent. So the fun thing is, you can not read the parent's location because of the same origin policy.

So what can you do?

```
var isInIframe = window.self !== window.top;
var isDifferent = false;
try {  // different domain is going to throw an error when you read it
  var foo =  window.top.location.href
} catch (e) {
  isDifferent = true
}
var showIt = isInIframe && isDifferent
```

Comment: interesting, so what you're saying is if the different domain is hosting the mydomain frame i cant access there parent location. I will try this out, and wonder if it will as well effect me since i have this page from `mydomain` iframed in a seperate page @ `mydomain` as well. Thanks for insight